# Button onClick writes text on another page

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm trying to make the button inserts text once I click on it. Basically like on this example but just that textarea is on another page and then "Hello" writes in it once button is clicked. Anyone can help me with that, thank you?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function insertText(elemID, text)
      {
        var elem = document.getElementById(elemID);
        elem.innerHTML = text;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <textarea id="txt1"></textarea>
      <input type="button" value="Insert some text" onclick="insertText('txt1', 'Hello');">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes it is possible and yes it is a bit complicated. first you need to learn about CORS. then learn about javascript message, you can pass text to another page using that.
and i see your stucture code are incorrect. i recomended to visited w3school.com and learn about the structure code firstly.

Comment: On another page? Another page where? Same computer/browser? Same domain or different domain? Need more details.

Comment: So if I have index.html and another.html on my website, where index.html contains button and another.html has an empty textarea. Once I click the button on index.html it will href="another.html" and place "Hello" in textarea.

Comment: @edge Do you want it to be saved, or only if the two pages are open at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer!

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form role="form" id="form" data-toggle="validator">
        <div class="input-group">
            <button type="submit" class="form-control" id="input" name="input" value="Hello">Click Me</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("submit", callme);
        function callme(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            let val = document.getElementById('input');
            localStorage.setItem('input', val.value);
            window.location.href = "another.html";
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

another.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <textarea id="input"></textarea>
  <script>
    window.onload = function () {
      document.getElementById('input').innerText = localStorage.getItem('input');
    };
  </script>
</html>
```